# how do i diagnose website not loading on mobile with 4g?

Tags: javascript, performance, heroku, mobile, netlify

Ok so I made a website and hosted it via heroku/netlify

It works fine on my phone via wifi, it seems to work fine on my laptop hotspotting off my phone 4g, but on my phone with 4g it just doesnt load....

I've looked at lighthouse, and webpagetest and nothing very obvious stands out to me, issues with image sizes so I learned how to compress my images and deleted my database of the larger ones, but still doesnt work, doesnt even load the homepage with no content on it.

Really don't know where to go from here, It's my first full stack project and and just don't understand why only via my phone and 4g it doesnt work.

edit:

So after further efforts it says function 'IDLE' is taking up 95% of my loading time... help?

Comment: You can debug your phone's Chrome remotely: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Ok, im seeing a lot of function 'Idle' time, like 95% of my loading time

Comment: Hmm... make a small test app and see if that loads correctly, I guess?